# Zend Framework: Chaining forms: how can I "unset $this->getRequest->isPost()"?

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is a pretty basic thing but I can't figure out how to solve this "properly" with Zend Framework:

Scenario:

1. Page displays form 1,
2. Page display form 2

This is a pretty basic thing but I can't figure out how to solve this "properly" with Zend Framework:

Scenario:

1. Page displays form 1,
2. Page displays form 2

```
class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action {  
    ...  
    public function form1Action(){  
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {  
           // save data from form1 in database  
           $this->_forward('form2');  
        }  
        // display form1  
    }  
    public function form2Action(){  
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {  
           // save data from form2 in database  
           $this->_forward('somewherelese');  
        }  
        // display form2  
    }  
}
```

When the user posts form1, first the if-condition in form1Action is executed (which is what I want), but also the if-condition in form2Action.

What would be toe proper way to "unset $this->getRequest()->isPost()"?

Note: the forms are build "by hand" (not using Zend Form)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `isValid()` at some point? This should stop you from processing the data in form2 when form1 is POSTed, unless of course they are exactly the same. Or use Zend's built in Multi-Page Forms documented here http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html

Comment: Makes perfectly sense, but in this case the forms are build "by hand", i.e. not using Zend_Form...

Answer (score 4):

You have three options:

1. Use `_redirect` instead of `_forward`. Forward redirects under the same request. Redirect will create a new request.'
2. Set a param in your _forward call, which you can check for in your second form: Such as `'form' => 2.` [More information.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.utilmethods)
3. Use the [built in multipage forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html#zend.form.advanced.multiPage) that are included in Zend_Form out of the box.

Comment: That's how I solved it for the time being, but I am not satisfied with this solution as creating a new request means more stress for the server. I would like to avoid this.. :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer to incude a new option. Option #2 which will provide a solution for you if you still want to use _forward.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set a class variable in action one and if it is true, don't run the code in action two.

Something like:

```
class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action {  
private $_fromAction1 = false;
    ...  
    public function form1Action(){  
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {  
           // save data from form1 in database  
$this->_fromAction1 = true;
           $this->_forward('form2');  
        }  
        // display form1  
    }  
    public function form2Action(){  
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && !$this->_formAction1) {  
           // save data from form2 in database  
           $this->_forward('somewherelese');  
        }  
        // display form2  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This last option did not work for me.

$this->_forward() creates a new instance of the controller, so setting a variable in the first instance does not affect the one in the new.

My solution was making $_fromAction1 static to share the variable between the 2 instances.

```
class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
private static $_fromAction1 = false;
    ...  
    public function form1Action(){  
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {  
           // save data from form1 in database  
FooController::_fromAction1 = true;
           $this->_forward('form2');  
        }  
        // display form1  
    }  
    public function form2Action(){  
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && !FooController::_formAction1) {  
           // save data from form2 in database  
           $this->_forward('somewherelese');  
        }  
        // display form2  
    }  
}
```